# Copy MDC context map to worker threads of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: spring-batch, mdc

We are using using spring-core 4.1.X module and spring-batch-core 3.0.X versions for a spring boot application. We are using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor for async working of threads. I need to copy MDC information from parent to child thread. I have seen using ThreadDecorators as best way to achieve this. But, i these are not available in version of spring we are using. Any suggestions on equivalent approaches with the spring versions we are using. If we cannot achieve using TaskDecorators, any suggestions on what is the other best way ??

Comment: These links might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009107/spring-batch-mdc-logging and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171559/accessing-job-information-for-mdc

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to the usage of [TaskDecorator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskDecorator.html) that was added in Spring **4.3** as a means [to create a custom MDC decorator and register it in a TaskExecutor, a process that is nicely described in this article](https://moelholm.com/2017/07/24/spring-4-3-using-a-taskdecorator-to-copy-mdc-data-to-async-threads/).

Actually this is a great idea especially since [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java#L74) has also been upgraded in Spring **4.3** to support `TaskDecorator`s.

If you cannot upgrade (which is the recommended approach) I don't think it's especially hard to extend `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` [to offer a similar hook if you see what is actually happening under the hood](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/a89e716cc71a8741385a0224b5d7eb7ce009e11a/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.java#L189).

[Here's the original commit on version 4.3 for SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor to support TaskDecorator's](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/25be5e060c26ad67d023620d3776c5d35e2d3b91#diff-79dc4ac8d60dd2323053eebb3d6c51cc)

Comment: thanks for the reply. So u mean, i need to create my own TaskExecutor class which extends SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and write my own implementation of copying MDC from parent to child thread and call method of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor?

Comment: yes. or skip the TaskDecorator similar structure and embed the MDC logic directly in the extended SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor. Not the most elegant of solutions of course but all that in case you can upgrade.

Comment: thanks. I have implemented my own TaskDecorator and called method of SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor from it. It worked perfectly

Comment: Great. If you found this answer useful you can upvote and/or accept it.